# How to delete an autofill URL entry in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Mozilla's help says to highlight the entry and press delete or shift+delete, but it doesn't work.

This is a mistyped site name that comes up in autofill in the URL bar.

The only thing I've found that will work is to open up the full history page, search for the bad URL, and delete all entries. But that's not very convenient considering how often mistyped URLs happen, and if there's an easier way I'd like to know how.

Comment: Are you selecting with the up/down arrow? Then shift+del should work.

Comment: @user3169 It doesn't.

Comment: What version Firefox? What OS? And how about FF safe mode?

Comment: @user3169 65.0.1 (32-bit), which is current as of today, Windows 7.

Comment: I found it doesn't let you delete it if you've already navigated to the URL and try to click the URL bar afterward. It has to show up as an entry in a list of search results.